# RabbitMQ Failed to declare queue and Listener is not able to get queue on server

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have **spring boot** **rabbitmq** application where i have to send an Employee object to queue. Then i have set up a listener application. Do some processing on employee object and put this object in call back queue.

For this, i have created below objects in my appication.

1. Created *ConnectionFactory*.
2. Created *RabbitAdmin* object using *ConnectionFactory*..
3. Request Queue.
4. Callback Queue.
5. Direct Exchange.
6. Request Queue Binding.
7. Callback Queue Binding.
8. MessageConverter.
9. RabbitTemplate object.
10. And finally object of *SimpleMessageListenerContainer*.

My Application files looks like below.

application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=foo
emp.rabbitmq.directexchange=EMP_EXCHANGE1
emp.rabbitmq.requestqueue=EMP_QUEUE1
emp.rabbitmq.routingkey=EMP_ROUTING_KEY1
```

MainClass.java

```
package com.employee;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
                MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

ApplicationContextProvider.java

```
package com.employee.config;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {
        context = arg0;

    }

    public Object getBean(String name){
        return context.getBean(name, Object.class);
    }

    public void addBean(String beanName, Object beanObject){
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, beanObject);
    }

    public void removeBean(String beanName){
        BeanDefinitionRegistry reg = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        reg.removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
    }
}
```

Constants.java

```
package com.employee.constant;

public class Constants {

    public static final String CALLBACKQUEUE = "_CBQ";

}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.employee.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id", scope = Employee.class)
public class Employee {

    private String empName;
    private String empId;
    private String changedValue;
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getChangedValue() {
        return changedValue;
    }
    public void setChangedValue(String changedValue) {
        this.changedValue = changedValue;
    }


}
```

EmployeeProducerInitializer.java

```
package com.employee.config;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.employee.constant.Constants;
import com.employee.service.EmployeeResponseReceiver;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(value="com.en.*")
public class EmployeeProducerInitializer {

    @Value("${emp.rabbitmq.requestqueue}")
    String requestQueueName;

    @Value("${emp.rabbitmq.directexchange}")
    String directExchange;

    @Value("${emp.rabbitmq.routingkey}")
    private String requestRoutingKey;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider(){
        System.out.println("inside app ctx provider");
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    };

    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(){
        System.out.println("inside rabbit admin");
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    };

    @Bean
    Queue empRequestQueue() {
        System.out.println("inside request queue");
        return new Queue(requestQueueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue empCallBackQueue() {
        System.out.println("inside call back queue");
        return new Queue(requestQueueName + Constants.CALLBACKQUEUE, true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange empDirectExchange() {
        System.out.println("inside exchange");
        return new DirectExchange(directExchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding empRequestBinding() {
        System.out.println("inside request binding");
        return BindingBuilder.bind(empRequestQueue()).to(empDirectExchange()).with(requestRoutingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding empCallBackBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(empCallBackQueue()).to(empDirectExchange()).with(requestRoutingKey + Constants.CALLBACKQUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        System.out.println("inside json msg converter");
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate empFixedReplyQRabbitTemplate() {
        System.out.println("inside rabbit template");
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(this.rabbitConnectionFactory);
        template.setExchange(empDirectExchange().getName());
        template.setRoutingKey(requestRoutingKey);
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        template.setReceiveTimeout(100000);
        template.setReplyTimeout(100000);

        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer empReplyListenerContainer() {
        System.out.println("inside listener");
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        try{
            container.setConnectionFactory(this.rabbitConnectionFactory);
            container.setQueues(empCallBackQueue());
            container.setMessageListener(new EmployeeResponseReceiver());
            container.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
            container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
            container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);
            container.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("inside listener finally");
        }

        return container;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("empReplyListenerContainer")
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer empReplyListenerContainer;
}
```

EmployeeResponseReceiver.java

```
package com.employee.service;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.ChannelAwareMessageListener;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.employee.config.ApplicationContextProvider;
import com.employee.model.Employee;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmployeeResponseReceiver implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

    ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider = new ApplicationContextProvider();

    String msg = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Employee employee = null;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel arg1) throws Exception {
        try {
            msg = new String(message.getBody());
            System.out.println("Received Message : " + msg);

            employee = mapper.readValue(msg, Employee.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is whenever i start my application, i get below exceptions.

```
2018-03-17 14:18:36.695  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-03-17 14:18:36.696  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5060 ms
2018-03-17 14:18:37.004  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-03-17 14:18:37.010  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-17 14:18:37.010  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-17 14:18:37.011  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-17 14:18:37.011  INFO 12472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
inside listener
inside call back queue
inside json msg converter
2018-03-17 14:18:37.576  INFO 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-8] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SimpleConnection@3d31af39 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/foo, localPort= 50624]
2018-03-17 14:18:37.654  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-7] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.655  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.655  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.655  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.657  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.658  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-8] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.661  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.660  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.661  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-9] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.666  WARN 12472 --- [TaskExecutor-10] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:18:37.667  WARN 12472 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:636) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:535) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1389) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ' in vhost 'foo', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ' in vhost 'foo', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2018-03-17 14:08:36.689  WARN 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ
2018-03-17 14:08:36.695 ERROR 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer received fatal exception on startup

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:563) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1389) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:636) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:535) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ' in vhost 'foo', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'EMP_QUEUE1_CBQ' in vhost 'foo', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2018-03-17 14:08:36.697  INFO 11076 --- [TaskExecutor-10] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.699  INFO 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.700  INFO 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.701  INFO 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.700  INFO 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.702  INFO 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-7] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-03-17 14:08:36.765 ERROR 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-8] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
2018-03-17 14:08:36.766 ERROR 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
2018-03-17 14:08:36.779 ERROR 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-9] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
2018-03-17 14:08:36.791 ERROR 11076 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
inside app ctx provider
inside rabbit admin
inside exchange
inside request queue
inside request binding
inside rabbit template
2018-03-17 14:08:38.978  INFO 11076 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@33b37288: startup date [Sat Mar 17 14:08:16 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-17 14:08:39.395  INFO 11076 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-17 14:08:39.398  INFO 11076 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-17 14:08:39.663  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-17 14:08:39.663  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-17 14:08:39.826  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-17 14:08:40.648  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-17 14:08:40.677  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-03-17 14:08:40.685  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
2018-03-17 14:08:40.746  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2018-03-17 14:08:40.747  INFO 11076 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-03-17 14:08:41.258  INFO 11076 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-17 14:08:41.270  INFO 11076 --- [           main] com.employee.MainClass                   : Started MainClass in 26.141 seconds (JVM running for 28.02)
```

Can anybody help me resolving my issue? As per my understanding, when object of **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** is being created, callback queue is not created on rabbitmq server. I tried declaring queue using **RabbitAdmin** object, but then execution stops and nothing goes ahead. This problem was not there when i was declaring queue in default virtual host. But when i added virtual host **foo** all of it sudden stopped working. You can replicate this issue using above code. I have pasted all my code. Kindly let me know if anything else is to be posted.

Interesting point is even if i am getting this exceptions, my application is up and running. That means somehow my callback queue is created and object of **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** gets the queue. I read somewhere that, when queue is created, my **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** object will listen to it.

Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This problem was not there when i was declaring queue in default virtual host. But when i added virtual host foo all of it sudden stopped working.

Does the user that accesses the new virtual host have `configure` permissions? Configure permissions are required to declare queues.

A RabbitAdmin is required to declare the queues/bindings; the container only does a passive declaration to check the queue is present.

**EDIT**

```
container.start();
```

You must not `start()` the container within a bean definition. The application context will do that after the application context is completely built, if the container's `autoStartUp` is `true` (default).

It is clear from your logs that the container is starting too early - before the other beans (admin, queue etc) have been declared.

Comment: Yes sir. the user have permissions to declare the queue with admin privilege. Let me know if you can replicate the issue with provided code.

Comment: The problem is you are starting the container too early - see my edit.

Comment: Hi Garry. Thanks. I got it. I removed start method call and its working now. I searched more on that, when bean is declared, queue is getting created passively. And it will get active when my app ctx is loaded properly.