# Failed to create RabbitMQ queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-cloud-stream

I received a suggestion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363167/handling-dead-letter-queue-with-delay/59364434#comment104940914_59364434), on a comment, saying that I might not have the Exchange I needed because my queues already existed. So, I manually deleted them all.

However, when re-deploying the application, I had the following exception for all the queues I had:

```java
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[myInput.group]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:721)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:598)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1472)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:992)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclarePassive(AutorecoveringChannel.java:364)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:980)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:700)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'myInput.group' in vhost 'production', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'myInput.group' in vhost 'production', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm not sure what this means, since I obviously want to create the queue `myInput.group`, and it seems to be complaining it does not exists...

I've also checked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334193/rabbitmq-failed-to-declare-queue-and-listener-is-not-able-to-get-queue-on-server) that my problem could be permissions. But I should have them - otherwise I believe I wouldn't be able to delete the queues...

Can you guide me to a solution?

---

The code from my previous question, to help you with the investigation:

```java
@Component
public class HandlerDlq {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandlerDlq.class);
    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";
    private static final String X_DELAY_HEADER = "x-delay";
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_RETRIES = 3;
    private static final int DELAY_MS = 300000;
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public HandlerDlq(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = MessageInputProcessor.DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        Integer  retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = 0;
        }
        if (retriesHeader > NUMBER_OF_RETRIES) {
            LOGGER.warn("Message {} added to failed messages queue", failedMessage);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED, failedMessage);
            throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Message failed after " + NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + " attempts");
        }
        retriesHeader++;
        headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader);
        headers.put(X_DELAY_HEADER, DELAY_MS * retriesHeader);
        LOGGER.warn("Retrying message, {} attempts", retriesHeader);
        this.rabbitTemplate.send(MessageInputProcessor.DELAY_EXCHANGE, MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION, failedMessage);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange delayExchange() {
        DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange(MessageInputProcessor.DELAY_EXCHANGE);
        exchange.setDelayed(true);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindOriginalToDelay() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION)).to(delayExchange()).with(MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLot() {
        return new Queue(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED);
    }
}
```

My `MessageInputProcessor` interface:

```java
public interface MessageInputProcessor {

    String INPUT = "myInput";

    String INPUT_DESTINATION = "myInput.group";

    String DLQ = INPUT_DESTINATION + ".dlq"; //from application.properties file

    String FAILED = INPUT + "-failed";

    String DELAY_EXCHANGE = INPUT_DESTINATION + "-DlqReRouter";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel storageManagerInput();

    @Input(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED)
    SubscribableChannel storageManagerFailed();
}
```

And my properties file:

```
#dlx/dlq setup - retry dead letter 5 minutes later (300000ms later)
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.dlq-ttl=3000

#input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.destination=myInput
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.group=group
```

---

EDIT:

I do have `EnableBinding` annotation in another component on the project (and now I've tried to add to the class HandlerDlq, but the error was the same), and I have the log entry:

> 2019-12-17 08:45:11.584 INFO 96124 --- [ main] c.s.b.r.p.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner : declaring queue for inbound: myInput.group, bound to: myInput

After that, there is an error message without stacktrace. Content below:

```
{ "written_at":"2019-12-17T14:06:59.263Z","written_ts":460692906701698,"type":"log","logger":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory","thread":"AMQP Connection <ip>:5672","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=503, reply-text=COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message', class-id=40, method-id=10)","tenant_id":"-","component_type":"application","component_id":"******","space_name":"dev","component_name":"*******","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"****","correlation_id":"-","organization_name":"****","space_id":"*****","container_id":"***","custom_fields":{} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `@EnableBinding(MessageInputProcessor.class)` on a configuration class?

If so check the startup logs; you should see

> 2019-12-17 08:45:11.584  INFO 96124 --- [           main] c.s.b.r.p.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner : declaring queue for inbound: myInput.group, bound to: myInput

Look for any errors there.

If you don't have `@EnableBinding` the provisioning is not performed and you will have to manually provision with `@Bean`s like your other queue.

If this "DLQ reprocessing" is a different app to the main stream app, then you should not have `@EnableBinding` here, you should properly configure the binding in the main app.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, Gary! I've added another part of the logs in the question - an error message I received after the `declaring queue for inbound` one you mentioned...

Comment: `unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'` - you don't have the `rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange` plugin installed in the broker. https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html